# .Net4\vs2010 versions of c# snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

Does anyone know if there are 'extra' .Net4\vs2010 versions of c# snippets like there was for  vs05 version (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718338.aspx or as mentioned [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/02/c-snippet-parity.html))?

I know I can import the 05 versions, or create my own, but wonder if there updated ones that use the newer .Net 4 (or I guess 3.x) features.

Answer (score 0):

There is one [Codeplex.Snippets](http://cpsnippets.codeplex.com/) project that can help you